# Video Streaming Mysql Return

Tags: php, mysql, sql, video, stream

MySQL gives me back 1 result, its a directorie, for  a video.
what can i do so that it shows 3 latest videos?

```
    <?php
$link = mysql_connect('mysql', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(database);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `videos`';
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['path'];
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know how your database looks like but you should order by the date (assuming you use that) descending and limit 3

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `videos` ORDER BY creation_date desc LIMIT 3';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

and put the mysql_fetch_array in a while loop

```
    while(row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo  '<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="/upload/'.$row['path'].'"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
  <br />';
    }
```

and replace the tag in your page with the `<?php require_once('sqlscript.php'); ?>`

Comment: ok got it, i have the code working i get 3 links, but how do i use the 3 to show videos? i could easily embeed one but because there are 3 now its different

Comment: how are you embedding the one

Comment: i had it like this but now its not working for some reason
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/upload/<?php require_once('sqlscript.php'); ?>">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>